# error trying to set up RFIDIOT on raspberry

Tags: python, software-installation, rfid, python-2.x, nfc

I am new to raspberry and python in general. I followed different guides to set up RFIDIOT (even the [documentation](http://www.rfidiot.org/documentation) and the installation guide on the [repository on Github](https://github.com/AdamLaurie/RFIDIOt/blob/master/INSTALL)). So far, when I run `pcsc_scan` it works fine and it gets the information of any card and the reader I am using ([ACR122U](https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/)). My problem right now it's with the "test the RFIDIOT" installation part. When I run any of the .py test files from it fails on the `import rfidiot` line. I have two Stacktraces at the moment, one if the reader has a card on it and the other if the reader has no cards.

Reader with a NFC card Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cardselect.py", line 25, in <module>
    import rfidiot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
    card= RFIDIOt.rfidiot(readernum,readertype,line,speed,timeout,rfidiotglobals.Debug,noinit,nfcreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.acs_set_retry(to)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 1320, in acs_set_retry
    return self.acs_send_apdu(self.PCSC_APDU['ACS_SET_RETRY'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 1186, in acs_send_apdu
    result, sw1, sw2= self.acs_transmit_apdu(apduout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 1211, in acs_transmit_apdu
    result, sw1, sw2= self.pcsc_connection.transmit(apdu,protocol= self.pcsc_protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartcard/CardConnectionDecorator.py", line 82, in transmit
    return self.component.transmit(bytes, protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartcard/CardConnection.py", line 146, in transmit
    data, sw1, sw2 = self.doTransmit(bytes, protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartcard/pcsc/PCSCCardConnection.py", line 205, in doTransmit
    SCardGetErrorMessage(hresult))
smartcard.Exceptions.CardConnectionException: Failed to transmit with protocol T0. Card protocol mismatch.
```

Reader without any NFC card error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cardselect.py", line 25, in <module>
    import rfidiot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/__init__.py", line 194, in <module>
    card= RFIDIOt.rfidiot(readernum,readertype,line,speed,timeout,rfidiotglobals.Debug,noinit,nfcreader)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 160, in __init__
    self.acs_set_retry(to)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 1320, in acs_set_retry
    return self.acs_send_apdu(self.PCSC_APDU['ACS_SET_RETRY'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 1186, in acs_send_apdu
    result, sw1, sw2= self.acs_transmit_apdu(apduout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rfidiot/RFIDIOt.py", line 1211, in acs_transmit_apdu
    result, sw1, sw2= self.pcsc_connection.transmit(apdu,protocol= self.pcsc_protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartcard/CardConnectionDecorator.py", line 82, in transmit
    return self.component.transmit(bytes, protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartcard/CardConnection.py", line 146, in transmit
    data, sw1, sw2 = self.doTransmit(bytes, protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/smartcard/pcsc/PCSCCardConnection.py", line 198, in doTransmit
    raise CardConnectionException('Card not connected')
smartcard.Exceptions.CardConnectionException: Card not connected
```

the .py test files I have are the same ones on [the github repo](https://github.com/AdamLaurie/RFIDIOt). I am running raspbian 9.4 (stretch) on a raspberry pi 3 model B+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am dumb. After a friend of mine gave me [this article](https://oneguyoneblog.com/2015/09/16/acr122u-nfc-usb-reader-raspberry-pi/) and I installed libnfc, the test files finally work. It wasn't easy to find out this was the problem, RFIDIOT documentation is kinda outdated and a lot of other guides out there don't specify much about it.

Comment: And what is the solution now? Installing `libnfc`?

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.